# How do I understand the connection of module components (e.g., code/design/frontend/template/block, etc.) in Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, module, architecture

I'm very new to Magento and am familiar with MVC and OOP and a lot of the design patterns that Magento uses. However, I find it difficult to understand the relationship between all the components of a module, specially because I am working on a codebase that has many custom modules. The documentation like [this](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-4.html) are not very clear for me. I'm sure those who are more experienced have found simpler ways to understand the architecture of customer modules

Answer (score 1):

Alan Storm articles about Magento1 probably still is one of the best resources. If you want to understand the architecture you should read it.

If you have specific tasks to do you can check inchoo blog https://inchoo.net/category/magento/ if there are some posts about the subject.

Unfortunatelly due to the fact that Magento 1 is at the end of life (currently only security patches are being released and they will stop after June 2020) many other resources have been removed or updated for Magento2. You can still try to check this list: https://github.com/aleron75/mageres

Or the most famous introduction for many many Magento 1 developers by Ben Marks: https://u.magento.com/fundamentals-of-magento-1-x-development (a little pricy for my taste but if you need to quickly familiarize yourself with the platform it may be worth it)